# Put json file content in an array unsing node JS

Tags: json, node.js, promise, bluebird, node-modules

So I have a dir where I have several Json files named by "the day and hour of creation".JSON . I want to create an array of all json content, meaning

FIle1.json

File2. json
.
.
.
FIlen.json

Should look [{FIle1.json (content)}, {File2.json},......{Filen.json}]

I'm a newbie in Node.json any help is welecomed

UPDATE

So I listed my files and now Icn't succeed to open them, here is my code bellow :

```
const testFolder = './report/';
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);
    fs.readFile(file, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(err, data){
      if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        }
       console.log('result read: ' + data);
    });
  });
})
```

And I get as a result :
I list the files:

> revision_2017-04-19T16:26:33+02:00.json
>   revision_2017-04-19T16:27:25+02:00.json

Then when I want to open them :

> { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'revision_2017-04-19T16:26:33+02:00.json']   errno: -2,   code:
>   'ENOENT',

Has anyone has any idea to solve this issue?

Thank you guys

Comment: How far have you got? Do you know how to open and read a file in Node.js?

Comment: I still don't know how to read and open a file. I'm really new to node.js

Comment: I think you should break the problem down in that case. Until you know how to open and read files, there's no value in asking about concatenating JSON arrays.

Comment: True. I'm able to list all my files for now, now I need to open them one by one I guess

Comment: I have a question how do I read the content of the list of files I get?

Comment: The error is quite clear, the file you're trying to open with `fs.readFile` does not exists, but the problem here seems to be the special characters that are in your file name : . It's weird, I've never encountered such character when I list and open files on my computer

Comment: Yes they exist thats the thing the files exist I have them in my directory 
I don't understand why he can't find them, since he did find them before when listing them

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is to list all the files in your directory, then open them all and put their content in a object.

To do so, you could use the `fs` module (filesystem) to list and open all your files, then put the content in an array :

```
const fs = require('fs');
let myArray = [];
fs.readdir('./your_directory', (err, files) => { // return an array that contains the names of the files in 'your_directory'
  files.forEach(file => { // loop over your files
    fs.readFile(file, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(err, data){ // open each file
      // the data variable represents your JSON file
      myArray.push(JSON.parse(data));  
    });
  });
});
```

And here you are, but you may want to get back to the main js scope, so you can either use Promises, or use the following methods :

- fs.readFileSync
- fs.readdirSync

They perform the same operations as the previous functions (readFile / readdir), but synchronously.

Hope it helps,
Best regards,